# How can I determine the browser's memory limit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The same javascript code behaves differently with Firefox (ok) and Chrome: "paused before potential out-of-memory crash".

Excerpt of code:

```
function setheuristicdist(full, f, i, t){
    const line = new Uint32Array(t.length);
    full[i] = line.map((h,j) => j < i ? full[j][i] : (j===i ? 0 : cordDistanceInKm(f,t[j])));
    return full;
}
...
const coords = gares.map(g => g.geometry.coordinates);
const heuristics = coords.reduce((ac,f,i,t) => setheuristicdist(ac,f,i,t), []);
```

The code is run in a dedicated web worker, computing a huge array, 2d-matrix of integer (19757 x 19757). Distance between two stations among 19757.

It works up to the end in Firefox, but stalls exactly at (15965 x 19757) in Chrome (also w/ Edge and Brave).
Are there different (Firefox/Chrome) limits in memory size ?
Tests made on the same computer, same load, under Windows 10. 64bits Intel 4 cores.
When the web worker ends up correctly, posted results are displayed on the DOM.

I may envision a work-around by computing two separate tables (10000 x 20000)+(10000 x 20000), but in the end the memory size will be the same, no? I would prefer the same program for Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Chrome crashes sometimes with workers without any reason and error messages ‍♂️

You can try to read your max heap size with `performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit` in a worker.

First I would recommend to optimize your code without unnecessary memory allocations (for example creation of intermediate arrays) and try to use `for` loops instead of passing callbacks to array methods (work with raw data as much as possible). You could use a typed arrays for your raw data. For example use Int32Array. Btw you can transfer typed arrays from workers to the main thread without copying, look for transferables.

If you can allocate a 19000 x 19000 matrix without processing then things are not bad. Just try process it optimally.

```
        function setheuristicdist(heuristics, f, i, t){
            const fcoo = f.geometry.coordinates;
            // const tg = t.map(g => g.geometry.coordinates); // avoid this, allocates an intermediate array
            heuristics[i] = t.map((g, j) => j < i ? heuristics[j][i] : (j===i ? 0 : distInKm(fcoo,g.geometry.coordinates)));
            return heuristics;
        }
        // try to change to a for loop
        const heuristics = gares.reduce((ac,f,i,t) => setheuristicdist(ac,f,i,t), []);
```

Comment: I did try with Uint32Array without any difference. Chrome doesn't really crash, it just pause the worker. I can't catch any error, and I can continue working on the main thread. I don't understand your point about 'cons tg', which I introduced precisely to reduce the size of original array t. I will try to add t.length = 0 to save a bit.

Comment: @allezl'OM you dont delete the old array but create a new one thus wasting memory

Comment: @allezl'OM tg is useless

Comment: Ok, tg is useless inside the function. I have computed it once before calling the function; It saves time (about 10%, what is great, thank you). But it doesn't really save memory. I do need to keep all the information in "gares" for the next step (the A-star algo for shortest path). See new code above edited.

Comment: OK, you are right! It also saves memory, at least enough to allow the Edge Chrome to let the web worker finish its job. Great.

Comment: N.B. `performance.memory` doesn't exist in Firefox (`performance` does, but for other info)